# Low voltage boost-converted versus high voltage on capacitor

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage, boost, high-current, low-voltage

Let's say I have a 7.4 V Li-ion battery that I boost-converted to 36 V, and I have a 36 V Li-ion battery. I want to know if a charged capacitor from a boost converter would release energy like a charged capacitor from a battery, because I know that a boost converter increases voltage and decreases current.

Comment: Is there any relation between that capacitor, the booster output, and the 36 V battery?

Comment: Batteries have better energy density than capacitors, generally lower power density, and much shorter lifetimes under charge/discharge. Every time you transform using a boost or buck converter, you waste energy. Those are the generalities. Now, what exactly is your application? Answering that might make make it possible for us to give you some advice.

Comment: I think I didn't wrote the question right, I meant that I want to know if a charged capacitor from a boost converter would release energy like a charged capacitor from a battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to know if a charged capacitor from a boost converter would
> release energy like a charged capacitor from a battery*

A suitable capacitor can produce peaks of thousands of amps if so desired and, you can more likely rely on a capacitor for delivering high transient currents compared to a battery. So, the fact that a suitable capacitor is charged to the same voltage as the battery means it can deliver higher peak load currents but, it won't be able to deliver those load currents for very long.

And, that's where the problem arises because, in order for a capacitor to deliver sustained heavy current, the boost converter has to supply a very high average current to keep the capacitor charged at the required voltage.

Given all of that, it's likely that a 36 volt battery will be **more suitable** at delivering sustained high currents to a load compared to a  boost regulator with a really good capacitor on its output.